# Spring boot application with custom ApplicationContext implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application that builds upon the Spring framework. To implement some of the requirements I had to provide my own implementation of the `ApplicationContext`.

Now that I moved to `spring-boot` I am wondering if there is any way to force the start up to use my implementation of the `ApplicationContext`?

**EDIT**: Provide some code

```
public class OpenPatricianSpringBootStandaloneApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(OpenPatricianSpringBootStandaloneApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(OpenPatricianSpringBootStandaloneApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String jreVersion = (String) System.getProperties().get("java.version");
        if (!jreVersion.startsWith("1.8")) {
            logger.error("JRE must be of version 1.8");
            System.out.println("JRE must be of version 1.8");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        logEnvironment();
        CommandLineArguments cmdHelper = new CommandLineArguments();
        Options opts = cmdHelper.createCommandLineOptions();
        CommandLine cmdLine = cmdHelper.parseCommandLine(opts, args);
        if (cmdLine.hasOption(CommandLineArguments.HELP_OPTION)){
            cmdHelper.printHelp(opts);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (cmdLine.hasOption(CommandLineArguments.VERSION_OPTION)) {
            System.out.println("OpenPatrician version: "+getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion());
            System.exit(0);
        }
        cmdHelper.persistAsPropertyFile(cmdLine);

        unpackPlugins();

        ServerLauncher.initializeApplicationContext(StandaloneConfiguration.class);
        OpenPaticianApplicationWindow.startClientUI(new String[0]);
    }
```

The context is created in the second last line:

```
public static void initializeApplicationContext(Class clientServerContextClass) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(baseServerContext == null, "Application baseServerContext is already initialized");
    baseServerContext =  new DependentAnnotationConfigApplicationContext(clientServerContextClass);
    logger.info("Initialize baseServerContext (" + baseServerContext.hashCode() + ") with class "+clientServerContextClass.getName());
    ((AbstractApplicationContext)baseServerContext).registerShutdownHook();

}
```

The `DependentAnnotationConfigApplicationContext` is the `ApplicationContext` implementation I am using. And this is how the spring applicationn is created without spring boot.

Comment: There's a public setter for `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applicationContextClass`. So I guess there might be a way to supply that while using the static `run(..)` method.

Comment: @phani: Taking a look at [`SpringApplication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html), I do not see any method to set the application context class. However there might be a possibility using the [`SpringApplicationBuilder`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html). Would you be willing to supply an example?

Comment: I never did this so a first-timer like you. How about http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#contextClass-java.lang.Class-

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `SpringApplicationBuilder` to define the `ApplicationContext` for your application:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-application.fluent-builder-api

In the [`SpringApplicationBuilder` javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html), you can see the methods provided by this builder for this:

- my first option would be using the `parent(ConfigurableApplicationContext parent)` method (naturally, your `ApplicationContext` has to be defined as a `ConfigurableApplicationContext`)
- otherwise try out the `contextFactory(ApplicationContextFactory factory)` one
- or maybe with the `initializers(ApplicationContextInitializer<?>... initializers)`

This documentation on [Spring Context Hierarchy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-servlet/context-hierarchy.html) might also be useful to come up with a suitable solution for you.

Answer (score -2):

There is an interface ApplicationListener which can be implemented and which takes many listeners like Refresh, Start.

```
public class ApplicationListenerBean implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = event.getApplicationContext();
    // now you can do applicationContext.getBean(...)
    // ...
}
```

}

Hope this will help.

Comment: This will not work, as the type of the `ApplicationContext` is wrong.